# Way to get specific user's ID

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

There is a self-made timesheet module. 
We are using few digital signatures (tableman, division boss, accountants and so on) to sign timesheets. Only users with their respective roles can see timesheets of the specific states (unsigned, signed, signed by division boss and so on).

As for now, accountants are making some timesheets for tablemen, who went on vacation. But due to restriction rules, after returning, tablemen can't see timesheets of their divisions, made by accountants.

Is there a way to get an ID of some specific user? So I can add accountant's ID to **domain_force** to make his timesheets visible for the respective division's tablemen. As I know, admin's ID = 0, but what about the rest?

That's how it looks now:

```
<record id="inf3" model="ir.rule">
        <field name="name">Tableman can do anything with 'unsigned' documents, made by himself or admin (0)</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="model_tabel_tabel"/>
        <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('tabel_inf_division'))]"/>
        <field name="perm_read" eval="1"/>
        <field name="perm_write" eval="1"/>
        <field name="perm_create" eval="1"/>
        <field name="perm_unlink" eval="1"/>
        <field name="domain_force">
            [('state','not in',['signed','signed2','done']),('create_uid' ,'in',[user.id,0])]
        </field>
    </record>
```